# How to check if wordpress W3 Total Cache plugin is active?

Tags: wordpress

which is the main class for W3 Total Cache plugin? I need to detect if plugin active or not from functions.php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
if ( defined( 'W3TC' ) ) {
  /* W3 Total Cache is active */
}
```

I would suggest that you use this within a hook though to avoid the possibility that your PHP file is processed before W3TC.